# SQL Trigger WHEN Clause compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that will check that the date entered is in range if the `Prog_Type` entered is `'FILM'`, however I receive a compilation error every time the statement is run.

> The error code is 00103, "Encountered a ; when expected ....."

then a list of many punctuation marks. From researching the problem I have seen references to a `DECLARE` statement, however I am not sure I would need to declare if the `Prog_Type` is created in the `Program_Table`, and I have reference that table in the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Prog_Made_Limits
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Prog_Made ON Program_Table
 FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.Prog_Type <> 'FILM')
BEGIN
  IF (:new.Prog_Made < date '1864-12-31' or 
      :new.Prog_Made > sysdate );
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Program Made date must be later than Dec 31st 1864, and earlier than today, if FILM is inserted');
  END IF;
END Prog_Made_Limits;
/
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `;` between `)` and `THEN`?

Comment: Amazingly, the error message is telling you *exactly* what the problem is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax almost fine, but you have a `;` after your `IF` condition which is causing the error. `;` is used to separate statements and consequent of your If is part of the the same statement as the condition.

This should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Prog_Made_Limits
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Prog_Made ON Program_Table
 FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.Prog_Type <> 'FILM')
BEGIN
  IF (:new.Prog_Made < date '1864-12-31' or 
      :new.Prog_Made > sysdate )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Program Made date must be later than Dec 31st 1864, and earlier than today, if FILM is inserted');
  END IF;
END Prog_Made_Limits;
```

I say *should*, because I don't have Oracle on my laptop, so can only test on SQL Fiddle, but by removing all semicolons I was able to get this to compile, however I think SQL-Fiddle treats semicolons as batch breaks rather than statement breaks, so I am not sure it is necessary to remove them all.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29aad/5)**

Comment: @GarethD - you can change which character is used to break up your statements, so that semi-colons will no longer cause problems.  For example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bd96/1

Comment: @jakefeasel every day is a school day! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have used the semicolon after the IF clause. That will end the statement. So please remove the column from that place and use the below code once:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Prog_Made_Limits
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Prog_Made ON Program_Table
 FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.Prog_Type <> 'FILM')
BEGIN
  IF (:new.Prog_Made < date '1864-12-31' or 
      :new.Prog_Made > sysdate )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Program Made date must be later than Dec 31st 1864, and earlier than today, if FILM is inserted');
  END IF;
END Prog_Made_Limits;
/
```